# Why is my Internet download speed so slow when connected to other servers than my ISP's?

Tags: networking, router, internet, download, isp

I'm having a 30 Mbps connection(FTTH). This is my speed test result obtained from speedtest.net

[Speedtest Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yUTP.jpg)

The last result is when connected with my isp's server.

I'm only getting the mentioned download speed when connected to a very handful of servers. But my upload speed is not affected in any manner. The download speed test result obtained from fast.com is only of 1 Mbps(maximum). But when accessing popular websites like Google, Microsoft, Youtube, etc I'm getting the mentioned speed. But when downloading from other websites like SourceForge, MediaFire, etc and also when torrenting I'm getting a download speed of maximum 8 Mbps.

Why is that so? Is my ISP throttling my download speed? Or is it because of poor ISP peering?

Comment: What country are you in? the top two are connecting to London and Berlin and geographic distance can play a part in bandwidth and latency, especially if you are in a country with poor links to the outside world.

Comment: @Mokubai I'm from India

Comment: Your ISP appears to be selling more capacity then they have.

Comment: @davidgo ok, I get that. But if that's the case, how am I getting full speed when accessing certain websites, like downloading from play store, playing youtube, or downloading from google drive.

Comment: Peering? Seriously, without at least trace routes or MTR/winmtr outputs I can't comment meaningfully.